# "pattern" for database-locking objects in django

Tags: python, django

I have this pattern in my django code because I need to do a database-level lock of the user object in case I need to modify it (POST or DELETE operations).
What I basically do is set a `locked_until` field to (now+timedelta (ie, 5 minutes)) consider the object locked if this `locked_until` is less than the current time. That gives me a failsafe in case an operation ended in someway it shouldn't (or the program died) and left the object locked.

But this pattern seems a bit confusing. Do you think something (ie, decorators) could make it easier to read?

thanks

```
def get_user(user_id, lock=True):
    if lock:
        with transaction.atomic():
            user = user.objects.select_for_update().get(user_id=user_id)                                
            if user.locked_until >= timezone.now():                                                   
                raise LockedException()                                                              
            elif user.locked_until != settings.MIN_DATE:                                              
                logger.warn('user_id=%(user_id)s, msg="user was left locked"', {'user_id': user.user_id}) 

            user.locked_until = (timezone.now() +
                                        timezone.timedelta(seconds=settings.LOCK_TIMEOUT))
            user.save()
    else:
        user = user.objects.get(user_id=user_id)

    return user


def user(request, user_id=None):
    user = None
    if user_id:
        try:
            user = get_user(user_id, lock=(request.method != 'GET'))
        except LockedException:
            logger.warn('op=user, msg="user is locked"')
            return HttpResponseServerError(jsonMessage('user=%(user)s is locked' % {'user': user_id}))
        except user.DoesNotExist:
            logger.warn('op=user, msg="user doesn\'t exist"')
            return HttpResponseNotFound(jsonMessage('invalid user=%(user)s' % {'user': user_id}))
        except Exception, e:
            logger.error('op=user, msg="unknown error", msg=%(exception)s',
                         {'exception': e.message})
            return HttpResponseServerError(jsonMessage(e.message))


    if request.method == 'GET':
        #...
        #do GET stuff...
        #...
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            #...
            #do POST stuff...
            #...
        finally:
            if user:
                user.locked_until = settings.MIN_DATE
                user.save()
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        try:
            #...
            #do DELETE stuff...
            #...
        finally:
            if user:
                user.locked_until = settings.MIN_DATE
                user.save()
```

Comment: You were right, there seem to be no race condition, as `select_for_update` effectively implements a mutex for the remainder of that transaction. I am sorry that I didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would make it easier to read is a context manager. That could factor out your try-finally clauses.

```
#...
if request.method == 'GET':
    #...
    #do GET stuff...
    #...
elif request.method == 'POST':
    with locked_user(user_id) as user:
        #...
        #do POST stuff...
        #...
elif request.method == 'DELETE':
    with locked_user(user_id) as user:
        #...
        #do DELETE stuff...
        #...
```